# quickblox, how to retrieve custom parameters in chat?

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

i'm developing an android application using quickblox api. I'm using chat SMACK functionality (1 to 1 chat) and i try receive message from chat. I can retrieve the message text, but i can't get customs parameters.

Here is a screen about my message variable:

[image]

The values i need are values stored in 'map' : tempo, telefono, stato, nome , prefisso.. how i can retrieve that? I just try to search on quickblox documentation, but i have an api error when try to implement DefaultPacketExtension.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to do it using QuickBlox Android SDK 1.1

To send message with additional parameters:

```
Map<String, Object> addinfoParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
addinfoParams.put(Consts.AGE, 22);
addinfoParams.put(Consts.TYPE, "actor");

final String BODY = "Hey QuickBlox!";

Message message = createMsgWithAdditionalInfo(USER_ID, BODY, addinfoParams);

Log.i(TAG, "message: " + message.toXML());
try {
    qbPrivateChat.sendMessage(USER_ID, message);
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

...

private Message createMsgWithAdditionalInfo(int userId, String body,  Map<?, ?> addinfoParams){
        Message message = new Message(QBChatUtils.getChatLoginFull(userId), Message.Type.chat);
        String addInfo = ToStringHelper.toString(addinfoParams, "", Consts.ESCAPED_AMPERSAND);
        MessageExtension messageExtension = new MessageExtension(Consts.QB_INFO, "");
        try {
            messageExtension.setValue(Consts.ADDITIONAL_INFO, addInfo);
        } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        message.addExtension(messageExtension);
        message.setBody(body);
        return message;
}
```

To receive message and get custom parameters:

```
chatMessageListener = new ChatMessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void processMessage(Message message) {
                String from = message.getFrom();
                String messageBody = message.getBody();

                List<MessageExtension> messageExtensions = message.getExtensions();

            }

            @Override
            public boolean accept(Message.Type type) {
                switch (type) {
                    case normal:
                    case chat:
                    case groupchat:
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        };
```

More info in Chat snippets https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/snippets/src/com/quickblox/snippets/modules/SnippetsChat.java